# Array with Object combination for Date and Time

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object, time

Ok so I am trying to use opjects with array, for the reason of getting the time of business hours open and close. I will eventually make a count down with the rest of this, trying having some tricky trouble getting the open and close when I use `document.write` , I've tried dot notations and the other way of calling objects `['open']`

```
var day = new Date();
var hours = new Array(7);
 hours[0]= {open:"8am",close:"10pm"};
 hours[1]={open:"8am",close:"10pm"};
 hours[2]={open:"8am",close:"10pm"};
 hours[3]={open:"8am",close:"10pm"};
 hours[4]={open:"8am",close:"10pm"};
 hours[5]={open:"8am",close:"10pm"};
 hours[6]={open:"8am",close:"10pm"};

var weekday=new Array(7);
 weekday[0]= hours[0];
 weekday[1]= hours[1];
 weekday[2]= hours[2];
 weekday[3]= hours[3];
 weekday[4]= hours[4];
 weekday[5]= hours[5];
 weekday[6]= hours[6];

document.write(weekday[day.getDate()]);
```

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong and how I should go about this. Great Appreciation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using getDate ... but you want getDay

```
console.log(weekday[day.getDay()]);
```

See this working fiddle of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/5mVct/

Comment: Ok great I see the console showing the object. so then I write `weekday[day.getDay()].open` correct

Comment: just waiting for the time to go up so I can accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Getdate method returns the day of the month not of the week. So you will most likely be accessing non-existant elements.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp

You are most likely looking for getDay() instead 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp